# How to wrap characters around a string?

Tags: string, haskell

We have been given an exercise where we have to 'frame' a string with a character input by the user. For instance:

```
*******
* AAA *
*A   A*
*AAAAA*
*A   A*
*A   A*
*******
```

I have previously defined strings to represent letters from a charecter into string, and also a function to manipulate the size of it, simply put as 'stretch'. I have tried to firstly surround these strings with asterisk and to try get the output, as the example above shows, but I keep receiving type errors. I am currently able to do it line by line (shown below) in terminal as I will show before but have had no luck implementing it into a function (also below)... any suggestions?

Line by line code at the interpreter:

```
EX01> map(\x-> "*" ++ x ++ "*")(letter 'a')
["* AAA *","*A   A*","*AAAAA*","*A   A*","*A   A*"]
EX01> top_and_bottom $$
["*******","* AAA *","*A   A*","*AAAAA*","*A   A*","*A   
A*","*******"]
EX01> map(\x-> x ++ "\n") $$
["*******\n","* AAA *\n","*A   A*\n","*AAAAA*\n","*A   A*\n","*A   >A*\n","*******\n"]
EX01> concat $$
"*******\n* AAA *\n*A   A*\n*AAAAA*\n*A   A*\n*A   A*\n*******\n"
EX01> putStr$$
*******
* AAA *
*A   A*
*AAAAA*
*A   A*
*A   A*
*******
```

My attempt at implementing it into a function:

```
stars :: Int -> String
stars 0 = ""               
stars n = '*':(stars (n-1))

top_and_bottom :: [String] -> [String]
top_and_bottom x =  (fringe : x) ++ [fringe]
  where
  fringe = (stars (length (head x)))

framestar :: [String] -> [String]
framestar x = putStr(concat(top_and_bottom(map(\x -> "*" ++ x ++ "*")[x])))
```

(P.S.: How could I also do this so it could take any character?)

Comment: try to relax a little. I was only making a lighthearted comment.

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, the `$$` in the interpreter demo aren't syntax errors but [a Hugs trick to recover the last result](https://www.haskell.org/hugs/pages/hugsman/started.html).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you solve a simpler more generic problem and think how you can use it in your case

```
wrap :: a -> [a] -> [a]
wrap x xs = x:xs++[x]
```

now you can apply this to your problem first for each row where xs is a row and x = `*`.  Second you can think your xs is the rows and x = "*****" (use correct length).  If you know and allowed to use `map` you use the wrap for each row, and second wrap once to the result.  It will be a one liner.